# Unable to loop over array / function using .length property

Tags: javascript, ajax

my code is in Spanish, hope that's not a problem. I am trying to call an array with objects(info) from a MongoDB using a GET call to show it as a table, I have defined the functions and functionality on the controller.js and services.js files but when I'm trying to iterate using the db info it shows me the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at mostrar_librerias (controlador_listar_librerias.js:7)
    at controlador_listar_librerias.js:29`

But I think everything is defined correctly.

this is the info on my controller:

```
    let librerias = listar_librerias();
    const tabla = document.querySelector('#tbl_inmuebles tbody');

    let mostrar_librerias = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < librerias.length; i++) {
            let fila = tabla.insertRow();

            fila.insertCell().innerHTML = libreria[i]['nombre'];
            fila.insertCell().innerHTML = libreria[i]['provincia'];
            fila.insertCell().innerHTML = libreria[i]['canton'];
            fila.insertCell().innerHTML = libreria[i]['telefono'];
            fila.insertCell().innerHTML = libreria[i]['email'];

            let celda_configuracion = fila.insertCell();

        }

    };
    /** I call the function to check that it works */
    mostrar_librerias();
```

services.js:

```
    let listar_librerias = () => {

    let libreria = [];

    let request = $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:27017/api/listar_librerias",
      method: "GET",
      data: {
      },
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      async : false
    });

    request.done(function (res) {
        libreria = res.listar_librerias;

    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

    });
    return libreria;

  };
```

api:

```
    module.exports.listar_librerias = function(req, res){
    libreriaModel.find().sort({Nombre : 'asc' }).then(
        function(librerias){
            res.send(librerias);
        }
    );

};
```

HTML body

```
    <body>

    <table id="tbl_librerias">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Provincia</td>
                <td>Cantón</td>
                <td>Teléfono</td>
                <td>Email</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/servicio_librerias.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controlador_listar_librerias.js"></script>
</body>
```

Please help.

Comment: Is the error on `for (let i = 0; i < librerias.length; i++) {`? That doesn't make sense, `listar_librerias` *does* return an array, `librerias` should *not* be `undefined`, though it'll be empty due to the asynchronous call

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, the error is occurring in that line.

Comment: Oh, you have *two* functions named `listar_librerias`, which do entirely different things (probably not a great idea)

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are probably right, but they are in entire different files and declared with local scope. BTW the array objects are taken the database so being empty is not a problem here.

Comment: It will be empty by the time the (upper) `listar_librerias` function returns, because you're not waiting for the array to be populated

Comment: The AJAX call is set to `async: false` which means `libreria = res.listar_librerias` is call before the function returns. The problem is probably that `res.listar_librerias` is `undefined`. I think your server is returning an array as a response, not an object. Try `libreria = res;`.